# Powering Multiple devices off one battery backup

Tags: batteries, backup

I have a 12v3a battery backup with 1 dc barrel connector on the end.

How can I power multiple 12v devices without needing to solder them, thus opening them and voiding the warranty.

One device is 12v1a the other is 12v1.5a.

I would rather not buy 2 of these backups.

Keep in mind I have never touched a soldering iron in my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to connect the devices in parallel, not series, if they all want 12 volts.

You can buy "Y cords" or "Splitter cables" that have a single female barrel connector and two or more male connectors - no soldering required. Male to female barrel connector cables are also readily available, if the splitter ends won't reach all your devices.

Comment: so like one of these? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B018OMJ2EA

Comment: @skatcat743: Yes, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I use a lot of 12 volt devices powered by 5.5mm x 2.1mm barrel connectors, from Arduino Unos to low-power MFJ ham radios.

The male side (the part that shows metal) is the power supply side.

There are a lot of splitters available on eBay and Amazon.  Some only split out to two connectors, and others can range up to 1 Female to 4 Male connectors.

I find that using "CCTV" as part of my search makes it easier to find them.

Here is one example:

[Super Power Supply® 5.5mm x 2.1mm 1 Female to 2 Male Splitter 2 Way DC Power Cable for CCTV Security Camera 5.5x2.1mm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JF8K6SO) for $3.99

[image]

Since your power supply is 3 Amps you should have no problem running several devices from it.